# Collect packages versions with ansible

Tags: ansible, apt, variables

Hi friends hope you're being well.

I got this very basic task i need to accomplish via ansible but i'm stuck with variable resiter :

i need to collect some packages version with ansible and display the output as :

host has 'this software : version'

here is the play:

```
---
    - name: Collect All Package Versions
      hosts: all
      become: yes
      tasks:
        - name: Update APT package cache
          apt:
            update_cache: yes
          become: yes
    
        - name: Collect Package Versions
          shell: dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\t${Version}\n' -W "{{ item }}"
          with_items:
            - firefox
            - libwebp6
            - thunderbird
          register: package_versions
    
        - name: Display Package Versions
          debug:
            var: package_versions.stdout_lines
```

When i execute it i got this message:

```
"package_versions.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

I know there is a problem with variable registration but i need a little hint.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the module *package_facts*. You'll get a dictionary of installed packages in the variable *ansible_facts.packages*. For example,

```yaml
    - package_facts:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item]|
                 map(attribute='version') }}"
      loop:
        - firefox
        - libwebp6
        - thunderbird
      when: ansible_facts.packages[item] is defined
```

gives in Ubuntu

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=firefox) => 
  msg:
  - 88.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
ok: [localhost] => (item=libwebp6) => 
  msg:
  - 0.6.1-2
ok: [localhost] => (item=thunderbird) => 
  msg:
  - 1:78.8.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

The results are lists because more versions of a package might be installed. If you want to take the first items add the filter *first* to the pipe

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item]|
                 map(attribute='version')|first }}"
      ...
```

If you put the list of the packages into a variable. For example,

```yaml
  packages: [firefox, libwebp6, thunderbird]
```

you can declare the dictionary *package_versions*

```yaml
  package_versions: "{{ dict(packages|
                             zip(packages|
                                 map('extract', ansible_facts.packages)|
                                 map('map', attribute='version'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  package_versions:
    firefox:
    - 88.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
    libwebp6:
    - 0.6.1-2
    thunderbird:
    - 1:78.8.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    packages: [firefox, libwebp6, thunderbird]

    package_versions: "{{ dict(packages|
                               zip(packages|
                                   map('extract', ansible_facts.packages)|
                                   map('map', attribute='version'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - package_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item]|
                 map(attribute='version')|first }}"
      loop:
        - firefox
        - libwebp6
        - thunderbird
      when: ansible_facts.packages[item] is defined

    - debug:
        var: package_versions
```

Comment: That's hell of a module and a very detailed answer. Thank you very much.